# OpenCV 2.4.3 FaceRecognizer doesn't recognize my face

Tags: opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm using cv::FaceRecognizer(EigenFaceRecognizer) to recognize my face.

I input 10 images of my face (which is photographed only my face. Not a background and size is 70x70, format is pgm) to train the recognizer.

Then try to predict exactly same photos that I used in training with Face CascadeClassifier and the Recognizer. But none of the photos are recognized as me!

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are probably doing something wrong, or maybe your input photos are too similar.

You should start with one of the tutorials on using FaceRecognizer, such as in the OpenCV official tutorials or Chapter 8 of the book "Mastering OpenCV". And then to improve your recognition accuracy, follow the recommendations at "http://www.answers.opencv.org/question/15362/opencv-and-face-recognition/" and "http://www.answers.opencv.org/question/5651/face-recognition-with-opencv-24x-accuracy/".

And for further questions about OpenCV, you should post them on "[answers.opencv.com](http://answers.opencv.com)" instead of StackOverflow, since that site has official support!

Comment: Thank you for a lot of articles and documentation! I will try Chapter 8 of Mastering OpenCV demo and then implement my code. and I'm gonna post questions on answers.opencv.com from now on.